# DaVinci Resolve doesn't load subtitles for M4V

Tags: davinci-resolve, subtitles

I have an .m4v movie with two subtitles tracks. When importing the movie into DaVinci Resolve 16, it only shows Video and Audio - no subs. 
Please advise, thanks.